# What's the Java equivalent of this C# reflection method

Tags: java, reflection, interface

I'm rewriting a framework originally done in C# into Java and this has me stumped. It's a method using reflection to return any property in a class that implements a particular interface using LINQ:

```
public List<TInterface> GetElementsOfType<TInterface>()
{
    return GetType().GetProperties()
        .Where(x => typeof(TInterface).IsAssignableFrom(x.PropertyType))
        .Select(x => x.GetValue(this, null)).OfType<TInterface>()
        .ToList();
}
```

I am trying to recreate in Java and so far have this. Not too sure if it's right though?:

```
public <T> List<?> GetElementsOfType(Class<T> klazz) {
    Class<?> props = this.getClass();
    List<T> elementsOfType = new ArrayList<>();
    try {
            Field fieldlist[] = props.getDeclaredFields();
            for (Field aFieldlist : fieldlist) {
                if (aFieldlist.getType().isAssignableFrom(klazz)){
                    elementsOfType.add((T)aFieldlist);
                }
            }
    } catch (Exception e) {
            return null;
    }
    return elementsOfType;
}
```

Update: Thanks everyone for your help. This seems to work for me although the unchecked cast causes a warning I had to suppress:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public <T> List<T> GetElementsOfType(Class<T> klazz) {
    Class<?> props = this.getClass();
    List<T> elementsOfType = new ArrayList<>();
        try {
            Field fieldlist[] = props.getDeclaredFields();
            for (Field aFieldlist : fieldlist) {
                if (klazz.isAssignableFrom(aFieldlist.getType())){
                    elementsOfType.add((T) aFieldlist.get(this));
                }
            }   
        } catch (Exception e) {
          return elementsOfType;
        }

    return elementsOfType;
    }
}
```

Comment: if you are using java 8 you can look at java 8 streams, it can pretty much do the same thing as the C# version above

Comment: Yeah using Java 8, not looked into streams

Comment: You want the args to `isAssignableFrom` in the same order as in C#

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Java, a property is not a field.  A property is defined as a public non-static read method and, if it’s not a read-only property, a public non-static write method.  An instance of a class with one or more such properties is known as a Java bean.

You can examine properties using the java.beans package, starting with [Introspector](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.desktop/java/beans/Introspector.html):

```
try {
    BeanInfo beanInfo = Introspector.getBeanInfo(props, Object.class);

    for (PropertyDescriptor prop : beanInfo.getPropertyDescriptors()) {
        if (klazz.isAssignableFrom(prop.getPropertyType())) {
            elementsOfType.add(klazz.cast(prop.getReadMethod().invoke(this)));
        }
    }
} catch (IntrospectionException | ReflectiveOperationException e) {
    throw new RuntimeException(e);
}
```

Because Java uses checked exceptions, you can’t easily use Streams to write LINQ-like code in this case.  It’s possible, but unwieldy.  And not worth the bother, considering the above code is fairly succinct.

(The reason for the Object.class in `Introspector.getBeanInfo(klazz, Object.class)` is that we don’t want properties of Object, namely the read-only `class` property of Object defined by Object.getClass().)

Comment: Unfortunately this just throws the IntrospectionException every time. Any ideas? I am calling it like this: List<Editable> editableElements = bingHomePage.GetElementsOfType(Editable.class);

Comment: What is the message of the IntrospectionException?  Does its stack trace contain any “Caused by” sections?

Comment: I think it might be linked to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4438815/javabeans-introspector-does-not-correctly-find-property-with-interface-hierarchy

Comment: That bug seems to be related to having get-methods and set-methods in different classes in the inheritance hierarchy.  Is that true of your props class?  If not, it’s more likely that the exception is in fact telling you what the problem is.

Comment: Thanks yeah I am having issues reading the stack trace atm (using VS code and seems like some issue there) but this sounds about right. Good news I have now got it working using my initial code (see update) but will def try to refactor it to get your approach working